# Sending client push notification using parse in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification

I am trying to send a notification to all subscribers using Parse.com.
I am able to receive when I do the push broadcast from the parse.com console.

However, I am trying to send the notification from the client app(Android).

I have tried the following solutions with no success:
Solution 1:

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
String message = txt.getText().toString();
push.setChannel("ABC");
push.setMessage(message);
push.sendInBackground();
```

Solution 2:

```
                ParseObject message = ParseObject.create("Message");
                message.put(AppConfig.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, username);
                message.put("body", txt.getText().toString());
                message.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        //Toast.makeText(activity.this, "Successfully created message on Parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Solution 3:

```
                ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
                pushQuery.whereEqualTo("channels", "ABC"); // Set the channel

                ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                push.setQuery(pushQuery);
                push.setMessage("New Update");
                push.sendInBackground();
```

Can Anyone please get and point me to the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled client push on your app's Parse Settings page? Client push

Comment: @kabuto178 Yes I have

Comment: I am in the same boat... cannot receive in the same application. I think this is what you are talking about.